# Automatically update the closing tag when open tag changes with Sublime Text 2 on Mac OS X

Tags: html, macos, sublimetext2, emmet

[image]

See the `H2` tags? How can I change them all to `p` tags without manually going from line to line. `cmd+d` is not viable because of the varying lengths of the inner content.

I found something called **Emmet Plugin** which I installed but can't get it to work. (Followed steps and confused by docs http://docs.emmet.io/actions/go-to-pair/).

Thanks for the help.

**--UPDATE--**

Not using a regex. Just to clarify I want something that will automatically update the `closing tag` if I change the `open tag`.

Comment: coming from visual studio i would love this feature also

Answer (score 10):

You need “Rename Tag” action:
https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#available-actions

Comment: [shift + cmd + k] on a mac

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + '  on Win

Comment: I know this is a very old answer, but if it is still relevant, please make it more clear. An answer should be more than a link.

Answer (score 7):

Alt + F3 works for me. I'm using the Emmet plugin, though.

Comment: Is that windows? Im on a MAC

Comment: That would be Windows, yes. I'm not a Mac user, sorry.

Comment: I know this is a very old answer, but if it is still relevant, please make it more clear. Alt+F3 does what when?

Comment: @randy if you’re using Emmet plugin, you can invoke Rename Tag action as any other action from Sublime Text (using Command Palette, for example) or add your own keybinding for this action, as described in plugins’ README

Answer (score 3):

I use Emmet and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> does not work for me.

I changed the key shortcut of the command.

`Preferences -> Key Bindings -> User`

Content:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+;"], "command": "rename_tag" }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions which does not require any plugins.
All solutions works on sublime2, sublime3 and atom

### Using Multiple Cursors (press shift-alt and down arrow)

- [image]

### Using Ctrl-D (if you want to restrict the update to some elements only)

- [image]

### Using ALT-F3 (to update all instances of h2 -> p)

- [image]

PS: For those who does not have the tags in same line, of they do have then all the contents are of different number of lines method 1 will not work both other methods will still work

Answer (score 0):

If you have [emmet](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#available-actions) installed: **Cmd+Shift+K** on mac, **Ctrl+Shift+** on windows

Answer (score -1):

Just use regexp. They are supported by Sublime Text 2 (in the CTRL + H).

Comment: Thank you, I was about to edit my question just to say without a regex. I want something that will automatically update the closing tag if I change the open tag.